# Xamarin xaml CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, xamarin, drawerlayout

I am working for the first time since a while in VS with Xamarin and I am trying to add material design to my app. I added the references to my project (Xamarin.Android.Support and dependencies).

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    ..........
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
   .......                                     
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

On both I am getting the message:

> element is not declared

Do I miss a dependency? I used the xamarin guide & google dev as to get what might be missing.

Maybe someone faced the same issue?

Comment: same here.. how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can't help you, but what i do when working with layouts in Xamarin and face a problem is copy and paste that layout in an project in Android Studio just to saw if it renders without problems.
Xamarin layout engine won't work with all kinds of available elements.